# Combining sequences with similar gene IDs

Tags: r, string, bioinformatics

I have a list of gene IDs along with their sequences in R.

```
$2435
[1]"ATGCGGGCGGGGGTCGTCGA"

$2435
[1]"ATGCGGCGCGCGCGCTATATACGC"

$2435
[1]"ATGCGGCGCCTCTCATCGCGGGGG"
```

I want to combine the sequences with the same gene IDs in that list in R.

```
$2435
[1]"ATGCGGGCGGGGGTCGTCGAATGCGGCGCGCGCGCTATATACGCATGCGGCGCCTCTCATCGCGGGGG"
```

Comment: What does your code look like?  Can we see it?

Comment: Did any of our answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use `lapply` after matching the names with `unique`. Here's some sample data:

```
A <- list("12" = "AAAABBBBCCCCDDDD",
          "34" = "GGGG",
          "12" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
          "10" = "FFFFGGGG",
          "10" = "HHHHIIII")
A
# $`12`
# [1] "AAAABBBBCCCCDDDD"
# 
# $`34`
# [1] "GGGG"
# 
# $`12`
# [1] "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
# 
# $`10`
# [1] "FFFFGGGG"
# 
# $`10`
# [1] "HHHHIIII"
```

Subset the related `names` and `paste` them together.

```
lapply(unique(names(A)), function(x) paste(A[names(A) %in% x], collapse = ""))
# [[1]]
# [1] "AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "GGGG"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "FFFFGGGGHHHHIIII"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
l <- list("A" = "ABC", "B" = "XYX", "A" = "DEF", "C" = "YZY", "A" = "GHI")
tapply(l, names(l), paste, collapse = "", simplify = FALSE)
# $A
# [1] "ABCDEFGHI"
# 
# $B
# [1] "XYX"
# 
# $C
# [1] "YZY"
```

Answer (score 2):

Bonus:

For a dataframe output, use this:

```
aggregate(unlist(A), by=list(id=names(A)), paste, collapse="")
```

Where `A` is you list.

Using @Ananda's `A`, I get this:

```
  id                                       x
1 10                        FFFFGGGGHHHHIIII
2 12 AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
3 34                                    GGGG
```